# Difficulty setting the 'Open with app' to an alias

Tags: macos, homebrew, symlink, alias, macvim

I am trying to set MacVim, installed via homebrew, to be the default HEX file editor.  I started this task by creating an alias to MacVim.app located in `/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-61` and placing the aliased app in `/Applications`.  This allowed me to see and open MacVim from the Application folder (more info [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/23653/4605)).

Now that the aliased app is there the "Open with app" selection via the `RightClick`->`Info` has the aliased app greyed out.  To make matters worse it does not allow me to browse/select the real app located in `/usr/local/Cellar`.

This doesn't seem to be asking to much here, any ideas on how to change this?

Answer (score 2):

Not the cleanest solution, but pressing `/` while in the `Open With` dialog allowed me to get to /usr/local.  Found the solution [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/7726/4605)

Answer (score 1):

I had a text file symlinked to my desktop. I was unable to associate an application to "open with" for the link, so I found the original file and was able to perform the action there. With "Get Info" I could set this app to always open files like this. Now when I open the link/alias, it uses the proper application.